# Determining the state of a system after a measurement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I'm confused about the state of a system after a measurement. Say we have a particle $v$ in the state: $ |\psi\rangle= \sqrt{1/4} \ |0\rangle + \sqrt{3/4} \ |1\rangle $.

From my understanding, if one were to measure the state of $v$, one would get the result $|0\rangle$ with probability $|\sqrt{1/4}|^2=1/4$, and similarly, $|1\rangle$ with probability $3/4$.

However, I've also learned that a measurement is always done by an observable (a unitary operator), e.g. $Z=|0\rangle \langle 0|-|1\rangle \langle 1|$, and that the outcome of the measurement is an eigenvalue of this operator, and that the state we get after the measurement is always dependent on the observable we use, and similarly for the probability of getting that state.

Now, by inspection, I noticed that when I measure $Z$, I do get the state $|0\rangle$ with probability $1/4$, and $|1\rangle$ with probability $3/4$, as expected.  But I don't get these results when I measure the Pauli operator $X$, for example.

Does that mean that the claim in my second paragraph always assumes a measurement of $Z$?

Comment: Do you mean to say expectation values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have written the state $| \psi \rangle $ in the eigen basis of $Z$ $(|0 \rangle, |1 \rangle) $, that is why $Z$ is diagonal. Since $Z$ and $X$ do not commute with each other they cannot be simultaneously diagonalised in one basis. If the operators commute then they can be simultaneously diagonalised and will have same eigen basis.

Measurement is always done in the eigen basis of an observable but its neither unitary nor Linear operation. The state after the measurement will be one of the eigen states of observable but its a random process that's why you can only come up with the probability of being in particular state.

You have to tranform your state $| \psi \rangle$ to some other basis by a unitary operator $U$ and then measure the result.